# Browsers picture width or height limit is 10000 px? How to rise above

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, firefox

[image]

**We've got two pictures - one of them 9 999px width:**

> http://www.picshare.ru/uploads/150912/b7DXF4HNsK.jpg
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/esf5d0qn/

```
<svg width="9999" height="3543"  x="0px" y="0px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 9999 3543">
  <image overflow="visible" xlink:href="http://www.picshare.ru/uploads/150912/b7DXF4HNsK.jpg" 
         width="9999" height="3543">
  </image>
</svg>
```

**The second image width of 10 001px:**

> http://www.picshare.ru/uploads/150912/PtqiS2dc9C.jpg
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/esf5d0qn/1
>
> (You **could not see anything** here ***by Fire Fox***, **Chrome** show error ***sometimes***)

```
<svg width="10001" height="3543"  x="0px" y="0px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 10001 3543">
  <image overflow="visible" xlink:href="http://www.picshare.ru/uploads/150912/b7DXF4HNsK.jpg" 
         width="10001" height="3543">
  </image>
</svg>
```

I truly need so big image, how could I do that? Maybe somehow split to the fragments?

Thanks

---

### Edit 1

I'm using Windows 7. Here 3rd image - 16535px width. I think now you have to find an issue here. I've got here *the same situation*, as for 10001px.

**The third image width of 16 535px:**

> http://www.picshare.ru/uploads/150912/2vz86d4eZ4.jpg
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/esf5d0qn/3
>
> (You **could not see anything** here ***by Fire Fox***, **Chrome** show error ***sometimes***)

```
<svg width="16535" height="3543"  x="0px" y="0px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 16535 3543">
  <image overflow="visible" xlink:href="http://www.picshare.ru/uploads/150912/b7DXF4HNsK.jpg" 
         width="16535" height="3543">
  </image>
</svg>
```

---

### Edit 2

When I divide the image 11 MB into two parts I have to save each of these images with 100% quality, that increases the weight of each from 5.5 to 9+ MB. You have to do this in order not to lose the quality (JPEG costs: c "You cannot resave JPEG without losing quality, even to the extent of 100 quality (it's not the highest quality, but mathematical optimization limit)"). So here the image with medium quality(60%). If I gonna save total size of 11 MB. And don't want to increase quality of half-part image more, then 5.5 MB(medium quality is this case didn't increase MB size)
[image]

That's why I'm looking for a way to display the browser image whose width is greater than 9999 pixels. Not cutting image into two parts to display each

Comment: No issue here with either browser, Windows 7 machine. You just gotta scroll a bit to see it.

Comment: Same here in Linux. What system are you using?

Comment: W7, You can also try to save the photo (www.picsh...) in the same directory where the svg file and try to open svg by different browsers - for not to go to the Fiddle

Comment: I added a request for a bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1204243